# mit-scratch : prevent sprite passing a certain boundary

Tags: mit-scratch

I'm making a beat-em-up game. Noting the image that you see, I want to prevent my sprite character from passing the fence in the backdrop or where it divides the the floor from the net ball stand. What blocks would I require to create a sort of barrier that stops my character passing that fence?

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can decrease the Y until the sprite is visually not passing the boundary

[image: Code]

Comment: You have to find out the "certain height" first though

Answer (score 0):

First, draw a line of any color at the bottom of the feet (or where you want it to stop)
Then, add this script.
[image: Code]